# Angular JS - get selected text of a select control

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I've followed the following link to solve the issue but it didn't work:
[How to get option text value using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552976/how-to-get-option-text-value-using-angularjs)

I have a dropdown that contains a set of servers. when i select a value from the dropdown, I want the selected value to display in a separate div. Here is what I have done:

Select control:

```
 <select name="source" class="form-control input-sm"
                        ng-model="filterOptions.hostId"
                        ng-options="s.id as s.hostName for s in physicalServerList"
                        ng-style="{'width':'100%'}">
                </select>
```

Displaying selected text:

```
<span class="pull-left">Source: {{ filterOptions.hostId.hostName }}</span>
```

However, this does not display the selected text. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not display selected text because your model will have the id of the selected item because of the usage of `s.id as s.hostName` (`select as label syntax`) in the ng-options. Just remove the `select as` part from the syntax,  have the ng-model hold the selected object's reference itself instead of just the id.

So your ng-option:-

```
ng-model="filterOptions.host"
ng-options="s.hostName for s in physicalServerList track by s.id"
```

and your model will be the selected object instead of just the id of the selected item

```
<span class="pull-left">Source: {{ filterOptions.host.hostName }}</span>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MNDbfv?p=preview)**

Answer (score 4):

Try this function:

```js
var hostApp = angular.module('hostApp', []);
    hostApp.controller('hostController', function($scope) {
    
      $scope.options = [
          { value: '1', label:'hosting1' },
          { value: '2', label:'hosting2' },
          { value: '3', label:'hosting3' }
      ];
        
      $scope.hostSelected = $scope.options[0];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="hostApp">
    <div ng-controller="hostController">
        <select ng-model="hostSelected"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>
        <div>value: {{ hostSelected.value }} <br />label: {{ hostSelected.label }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```